Trying to create an executable using pyinstaller that contains both a custom icon and the console window
like the title says, I am trying to create a pyinstaller application that has an icon using the --icon argument, but it seems that the icon only successfully appears whenever I also use --windowed. The problem is using --windowed hides the console window, and I would still like that to appear. My command currently looks like this:
Pyinstaller --clean --console --onefile --add-data 'res:res'  --icon icons/icon_test.ico --name 'test app' test_file.py

Whenever I run this, the executable is created, but without the icon. Whenever I include --windowed, the executable is created with the icon, but with no console window. Am I asking for the impossible?
